# How can I import a library in gradle project Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to import this library: https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

As mentioned on the README I added following in my `build.gradle`

```
 compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.3.0'
```

and added the following in my xml

```
<com.makeramen.RoundedImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/photo1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:corner_radius="30dip"
        app:border_width="2dip"
        app:border_color="#333333"
        app:round_background="true"
        app:is_oval="true" />
```

After this if I `Rebuild Project` I keep getting an error

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'round_background' in package 'com.myapp'
```

Should I be doing something else to import a library in my gradle project?

Comment: I think its the namespace. You should use the package name.

Comment: `round_background` is `now mutate_background`-------from [here](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView).

Answer (score 1):

You must have forgot to sync your project with gradle file.

- Go to: Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle files
- Or write this in your build.gradle

Code:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `attrs` on library:

https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView/blob/master/roundedimageview/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml

The `round_background` attribute doesn't exist.
If you check the history, this attribute has been changed in `mutate_background`

https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView/commit/6d734ca0b99b7541039a03da615e7420b7b8238d

Change your xml:

```
<com.makeramen.RoundedImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/photo1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:corner_radius="30dip"
        app:border_width="2dip"
        app:border_color="#333333"
        app:mutate_background="true"
        app:is_oval="true" />
```